# Removing from multiMap

Tags: java, collections, multimap

In school we are to implement our own class MultiMap.

When I were implementing the remove method, I ran in to some trouble.

My problem is when I call the remove method, the set.Remove(value) returns false. Just like if the set didn't contain the object.

I've tried to write out the object refferences from the main, and the object reference from the MultiMap class, and the objects seems to be the same.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Here's my map code :

```
public class MultiMap<K, V> {

private final Map<K, Set<V>> map = new HashMap<>();

public MultiMap() {
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Set<K> keys = map.keySet();
    for (K k : keys) {
        sb.append("key ");
        sb.append(k);
        sb.append(" Value ");
        sb.append(map.get(k));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public int size() {
    return map.size();
}

    public boolean put(K key, V value) {
    Set<V> set;
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        set = map.get(key);
        set.add(value);
    } else {
        set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(value);
    } 
    return (map.put(key, set) != null) ? false : true;
}

public Set<V> get(K key) {
    return map.get(key);
}

public void remove(K key, V value) {
    Set<V> set = map.get(key);
    System.out.println(value);
    System.out.println(set.remove(value));
    if(set.isEmpty()) {
        map.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person("navn");
    Collection<Person> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(p);
    MultiMap map = new MultiMap<>();
    map.put(1, set);
    System.out.println(map.toString());
    System.out.println(map.get(1));
    map.remove(1, p);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you `remove` returns `false` because you are trying to remove `Person` object, but you don't have it in the `map`.
Notice you are adding `Collection<Person>` to `map`, but trying to remove `Person`, obviously those 2 objects are not `equal`, therefore you get `false` value.

after : `map.put(1, set);` in memory you have something like :
`1=>[[p]];` but ,i guess, you expected `1=>[p]`.

just replace `map.put(1,set);` with `map.put(1,p);`

Also take a look at `Guillaume Poussel` answer for proper MultiMap implementation advice.

Comment: It is not the map.remove that returns false, but it is the set.remove() method that returns false. I do not wan't to remove the whole set from the map, but I want to remove a person, from a set in the map.

Answer (score 5):

The first problem is in your `put()` method. You shall not create a new `HashSet` every time you insert a new element.
You should first check whether your underlying map contains the provided key, by using `containsKey()`. If the key exists, just add the new value. Otherwise, create a new `HashSet` and keep your code.

Then, you will have to fix your `remove()` method. It will raise a `NullPointerException` if the key does not exists. Indeed, `map.get(key)` will return `null` and `set.remove()` will fail.

---

**EDIT:**

See [@Eugen Halca answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19772042/263057) about your Multimap usage. In your `main()` method, you are adding a `Collection` of `Person`, but trying to remove a single `Person`. Even with the best `Multimap` implementation, that won't work ;)

Comment: Thx for your answer. I fixed the put() method so far, and changed my first post so it fits to this. But I'm not rly sure I understand how you want me to fix remove?

Comment: When you remove an element, you cannot be sure the key exists in your Multimap. So `map.get(key)` can return `null`. As an example, try `map.remove(2, p)`.